# File uploading in Lightning

Tags: lightning

I have an urgent requirement of uploading large multiple files from salesforce to dropbox directly without saving it to the Attachments.

Can someone help me in that ? Just need a way to create a blob of the Uploaded large content in apex.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Due to payload limits, you won't be able to exceed approximately 3.9MB files if you choose to go through Apex (Lightning has a maximum of a 5MB payload, and binary files must be encoded). You'll want to post them directly to the dropbox API. As long as you follow the rules for CORS [in the documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation), you can send files up to the maximum allowed by Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to try AppExchange app?

Check out the following links -

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000prqLEAQ

https://www.dropbox.com/help/business/salesforce-admin